# I want to open a folder in particular path in many subfolder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below the javascript program for open a Folder. This program works fine.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function OpenFile()
      {
          window.open("G:/Informa/TandF/Source/IART/Vol00000/170001/Source", "_self")
      }
   </script>
```

In below i have change the "170001" to ".." because in the folder "Vol00000" in many folder contain in only one folder have the "Source" folder. I want to open a folder in this concept.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function OpenFile()
      {
          window.open("G:/Informa/TandF/Source/IART/Vol00000/../Source", "_self")
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: can js open local file ? :O

Comment: @xFighter Javascript is not opening anything here. It's opening a new browser window, and the browser will likely try to use the `file://` protocol to show a local file. But the original page that issued that `window.open` has no way of accessing the data. Of course it will be on the local machine, not on the server. So for displaying a user a list of files with reports on their machine this is uncommon, but totally fine.

Comment: @xFighter In fact, js _can_ open local files. Read about `FileReader` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader